# Flutter get error after update to 1.12.13+hotfix.5

Tags: flutter

I'm getting this error after I upgrade flutter.

Because no versions of **datetime_picker_formfield** match **>0.4.3 <0.5.0** and **datetime_picker_formfield** 0.4.3 depends on intl ^0.15.8, **datetime_picker_formfield** ^0.4.3 requires intl ^0.15.8.
And because every version of **flutter_localizations** from sdk depends on intl 0.16.0, **datetime_picker_formfield** ^0.4.3 is incompatible with **flutter_localizations** from sdk.
So, because ***APP_NAME*** depends on both **flutter_localizations** any from sdk and **datetime_picker_formfield** ^0.4.3, version solving failed.

Please help.
Thanks.

Comment: In this case posting your pubspec.yaml code would help others figure out the solution.

Comment: @dlohani I use **datetime_picker_formfield** and **flutter_localization**. when using both of these packages, I always got error. My solution is just remove **datetime_picker_formfield** and use other package instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding these to your pubspec.yaml file:

```
dependency_overrides:
    intl: ^0.16.0
```